# Fold corner of a SVG playingcard, revealing the other side

Tags: javascript, svg, matrix, 3d, css-animations

With some elbow grease I managed to create a 2D version of the effect:

[image]

But it feels contrived. I would like to animate this, change the size and the angle.

Before I start digging into maths to calc all those hardcoded coordinates...

Can this be done in a smarter way? (Without dependencies on 3rd party libraries)

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 278" style="height:180px">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="back" width="200" height="278" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <image width="200" href="https://svg-cdn.github.io/cm-back-red.svg" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="front" width="200" height="278" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <image width="200" href="https://svg-cdn.github.io/cm-hearts-king.svg" />
        </pattern>
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <path d="M0 178L0 0h200v278h-59z" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#clip)">
        <rect width="200" height="278" fill="url(#back)" />
        <rect width="200" height="278" fill="url(#front)" 
              transform="translate(-100 139) rotate(-100 100 139)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

## Version 1

From CCProg his answer, Heiko his answer takes some more work.

- My math fails me again, how to make the card corner follow the mouse position. It now calculates the `x` and `y` offsets.
- And a full card turn would be cool

[image]

```js
customElements.define("fold-card", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
        .innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0 0 300 378" style="height:95vh;cursor:hand;background:pink">
    <defs><pattern id="back" width="200" height="278" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><image width="200" href="https://svg-cdn.github.io/cm-back-red.svg" /></pattern>
        <pattern id="front" width="200" height="278" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><image width="200" href="https://svg-cdn.github.io/cm-hearts-king.svg" /></pattern>
        <clipPath id="clip"><path /></clipPath></defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#clip)">
        <rect width="200" height="278" fill="url(#back)" />
        <rect id="below" width="200" height="278" fill="url(#front)" />
    </g></svg>`;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      let svg = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("svg");
      let pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
        let [x,y] = (this.getAttribute("crease")||"0,0").split(",");
        this.fold({x,y});
      this.onmousemove = evt =>{
        pt.x = evt.clientX;
        pt.y = evt.clientY;
        this.fold( pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse()) );
      }
    }
    fold({x,y}){
      if(x>=0 && x<=200 && y>=0 && y<=278) {
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#clip path')
          .setAttribute('d', `M0 ${y}L0 0H300V278H${x}z`);
        let a = Math.atan2(x, 278 - y) * 180 / Math.PI;
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#below')
          .setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${-2*a} 0 ${y}) translate(-200)`);
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<style> fold-card { height: 180px } </style>
<fold-card crease="200,10"></fold-card>
<fold-card crease="100,50"></fold-card>
```

## Version 2 - almost no Math using `<marker>`

**chrwahl** his answer is cleverly using a `<marker>` to position the revealing card at the end of a **rotating** `<line>`

Work in progress: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/r2y7x3fd/

Still need to calculate the position of the **red dot**, to create a `<clip-path>`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Don't fear the math, it is really quite simple.

Start with the two points where the "crease" meets the card sides, because you can choose them freely.

```
P1 = 0, 178    // x is fixed
P2 = 141, 278  // y is fixed
```

Compute the angle of the "crease" from the vertical in degrees:

```
a = Math.atan2((P2.x - P1.x), (P2.y - P1.y))*180/Math.PI
  = Math.atan2(141, 100)*180/Math.PI
  = 54.655
```

Move the second card to the left side of the y-axis

```
transform ="translate(-200)"
```

...and rotate it by `-2a` around `P1`

```
transform ="rotate(-109.31 0 178) translate(-200)"
```

That's all.

```js
function crease (y1, x2) {
  document.querySelector('#clip path')
          .setAttribute('d', `M0 ${y1}L0 0H200V278H${x2}z`);
  
  const a = Math.atan2(x2, 278 - y1)*180/Math.PI;
  document.querySelector('#below')
          .setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${-2*a} 0 ${y1}) translate(-200)`);
}

crease(178, 141);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 278" style="height:180px">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="back" width="200" height="278" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <image width="200" href="https://svg-cdn.github.io/cm-back-red.svg" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="front" width="200" height="278" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <image width="200" href="https://svg-cdn.github.io/cm-hearts-king.svg" />
        </pattern>
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <path />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#clip)">
        <rect width="200" height="278" fill="url(#back)" />
        <rect id="below" width="200" height="278" fill="url(#front)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: See version 1 in my question. Does doing an actual turn require a 3 parameter? (sorry math was 40 years ago)

Comment: You've seen the typo? `x>=0`, not `x=>0`.

Comment: Fixed, that's what I said, my math sucks and my IDE doesn't warn about incorrect arrow function notation. 

Comment: btw, the arrow function is a truthy value, so nothing to warn about...

Comment: (Sorry, my previous attempt did contain some errors. Without testing, this looks like the correct formula – my math is almost as far away...) For finding the points for the crease, you need points equidistant from the bottom left corner and the mouse position. For P1: `278 - y1 = Math.hypot(cx, y1-cy) => y1 = (cx*cx + cy*cy - 278*278)/2/(278 + cy)`. For P2: `x2 = Math.hypot(x2-cx, 278-cy) => x2 = (cx*cx + (278-cy)*(278-cy))/2/cx`.

Comment: ...tested now, and for P1 it is `y1 = (cx*cx + cy*cy - 278*278)/2/(cy - 278)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an animated solution that uses the CSS [`rotate3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d) transformation. I achieved it with quite some trial and error, and it is still not clear to me how exactly the `transform-origin` affects the animation.

I found that the animation changes when I move the `transform-origin: 81px bottom;` rule from `div.back` to `input:checked~div.back.corner`. Apparently, elements should have the same `transform-origin` before and after the animation for it to be smooth, even if the element before the animation is not transformed at all.

I have added a Javascript function that computes all the parameters from just the height and width and the x and y coordinates of the "crease".

```js
var rules = document.styleSheets[0].rules;

function render(form) {
  rules[1].styleMap.set("width", `${form.w.value}px`);
  rules[1].styleMap.set("height", `${form.h.value}px`);
  rules[2].styleMap.set("transform-origin", `${form.x.value}px bottom`);
  rules[3].styleMap.set("clip-path", `path("M${form.w.value},${form.h.value} l${-form.x.value},0 l${form.x.value},${-form.y.value} l0,${form.y.value}z")`);
  rules[3].styleMap.set("transform", `translateX(${form.x.value - form.w.value / 2}px) rotateY(180deg) translateX(${form.w.value / 2 - form.x.value}px)`);
  rules[3].styleMap.set("transform-origin", `${form.w.value - form.x.value}px bottom`);
  rules[4].styleMap.set("clip-path", `path("M0,0 l${form.w.value},0 l0,${form.h.value} l${form.x.value - form.w.value},0 l${-form.x.value},${-form.y.value} l0,${form.y.value-form.h.value}z")`);
  rules[5].styleMap.set("clip-path", `path("M0,${form.h.value} l${form.x.value},0 l${-form.x.value},${-form.y.value} l0,${form.y.value}z")`);
  rules[6].styleMap.set("transform", `rotate3d(${-form.x.value}, ${-form.y.value}, 0, -170deg)`);
  rules[7].styleMap.set("transform", `translateX(${form.x.value - form.w.value / 2}px) rotateY(180deg) translateX(${form.w.value / 2 - form.x.value}px) rotate3d(${form.x.value}, ${-form.y.value}, 0, -170deg)`);
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 278px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  zoom: 0.5;
}

div.back {
  background: url(https://svg-cdn.github.io/cm-back-red.svg);
  transform-origin: 81px bottom;
}

div.front {
  background: url(https://svg-cdn.github.io/cm-hearts-king.svg);
  clip-path: path("M200,278 l-81,0 l81,-99 l0,99z");
  transform: translateX(-19px) rotateY(180deg) translateX(19px);
  transform-origin: 119px bottom;
}

div.nocorner {
  clip-path: path("M0,0 l200,0 l0,278 l-119,0 l-81,-99 l0,-179z");
}

div.corner {
  clip-path: path("M0,278 l81,0 l-81,-99 l0,99z");
}

input:checked~div.back.corner {
  transform: rotate3d(-81, -99, 0, -170deg);
}

input:checked~div.front {
  transform: translateX(-19px) rotateY(180deg) translateX(19px) rotate3d(81, -99, 0, -170deg);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="render(this); return false;">
  width <input name="w" size="3" value="200" />
  height <input name="h" size="3" value="278" />
  x axis <input name="x" size="3" value="81" />
  y axis <input name="y" size="3" value="99" />
  <input type="submit" value="Render" />
</form>
<input type="checkbox" /> Fold
<div class="back nocorner"></div>
<div class="back corner"></div>
<div class="front"></div>
```

**Remark on the "interactive card folder":** If the folded card corner is (x, bottom - y), then the crease goes from ((x²+y²)/2x, bottom) to (0, bottom - (x²+y²)/2y).

Comment: Interesting, I added a ``zoom:0.6`` to fit the SO snippet height. There is some overflow happing. Have to investigate this with multiple cards on the table

Comment: Cool addition, now the next holy grail is starting this fold animation and then **turn** the card  

Comment: You mean turn the whole card (undoing the fold)?

Comment: Yes, like you would turn a real card. Those flip animations I now use are lame compared with your work  My old Web Component, I did years ago, is at: https://cardmeister.github.io/

Comment: You have more control over animations with [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

Answer (score 2):

This is not perfect, but maybe you can work more in this direction. I really did some experimentation here.

The front card is a marker, making it follow the angle of the line that it is placed on. The line is then positions according to the mouse. The mask that cuts off the cards in the bottom is made with a line that has a wide (large) stroke and fixed in the bottom left corner.

```js
let SVG   = document.getElementById("SVG");
let LINE1 = document.getElementById("LINE1");
let LINE2 = document.getElementById("LINE2");

const toSVGPoint = (x, y) => (new DOMPoint(x, y)).matrixTransform(SVG.getScreenCTM().inverse());

SVG.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let p = toSVGPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  LINE1.setAttribute('x2', p.x);
  LINE1.setAttribute('y2', p.y);
  LINE1.setAttribute('x1', 0-p.x);
  LINE1.setAttribute('y1', 278-p.x);
  
  LINE2.setAttribute('x2', p.x);
  LINE2.setAttribute('y2', p.y);
});
```

```html
<svg id="SVG" viewBox="0 0 300 278" style="height:180px">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="back" width="200" height="278" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <image width="200" href="https://svg-cdn.github.io/cm-back-red.svg" />
    </pattern>
    <mask id="mask1">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <line id="LINE2" x1="0" y1="278" x2="0" y2="278"
        stroke="black" stroke-width="500"
        stroke-dasharray="50 50" pathLength="100" />
    </mask>
    <marker id="card" viewBox="-278 0 278 200" refX="0" refY="0"
      markerWidth="278" markerHeight="200"
      markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto">
      <image transform="rotate(90)" width="200"
        href="https://svg-cdn.github.io/cm-hearts-king.svg" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#mask1)">
    <rect class="back" width="200" height="278" fill="url(#back)" />
    <line id="LINE1" x1="0" y1="278" x2="0" y2="0" stroke="none" marker-end="url(#card)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Welcome to the challenge! Everyone is going to get credits on https://playing-card.github.io (empty for now)

Comment: I tried your solution and found it produced the following incorrect rendering: https://i.stack.imgur.com/An0Hk.png.

Comment: I edited your code a bit to make it clearer (for me) what is happening. I totally like the no-math approach (but will always have respect for CCProg his math answers).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen You are right. I'm not happy either. I really struggled getting it to work and it is not even close. The problem is to calculate the position of the other end of the card.

Comment: Does the remark at the end of my answer help?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman That is just fine. Yes, that was exactly the goal not to do too many calculations.

Comment: Getting close, after a days work, still need to add some Math (line intersections) to calculate the reddot position: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/r2y7x3fd/